# Generate TableAdapter from SQL query in SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a query that looks like this

```
DECLARE @sql1 as nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql1='.......'

DECLARE @sql2 as nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql2='.......'

DECLARE @sql3 as nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql3='.......'

exec (@sql2+@sql1+@sql3)
```

This query should return a table with certain columns so and fill my DataTable with said columns.
However, when I try to create my TableAdapter in VS2013 I get an error in the TableAdapter configuration wizard saying:

```
Generated SELECT statement.
  The DECLARE SQL construct or statment is not supported.
```

Anyone have any idea on how can i create that TableAdapter with the result of my query?

Comment: why would you create a tableadapter for SSRS?

Comment: Which SQL server version did you use?

Comment: I would not do this via the wizard.  Create your data source in the report and then your dataset is where you can put in your SQL.  If your SQL runs in SSMS and returns data, it should work in your dataset as well.